# Are Gmail, Facebook and WhatsApp still accessible in Macau, and in Hong Kong in 2022?

Tags: hong-kong, internet, communication, macau

Three years ago the Trip Advisor answers to [Does Gmail, Facebook and WhatsApp work in Hong Kong and Macau](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294217-i1496-k12030777-Does_gmail_Facebook_WhatsApp_work_in_hong_kong_and_macau-Hong_Kong.html) all seem to say:

> They all work.

Has anything changed, or are Gmail, Facebook and WhatsApp still accessible in Macau, and in Hong Kong in 2022?

**note:** *I'm primarily interested in Gmail*, but to make answers more useful for other readers I kept the three together here.

Comment: First of all GFW doesn't apply to international roaming, nor any (current or future) SARs (because it's part of the "S"). For anywhere where GFW is in effect Cloudflare WARP is your friend.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for now , Hong Kong and Macau still operates outside of the Great Firewall. As this [article](https://www.aljazeera.com/economy/2022/2/17/as-great-firewall-looms-fears-for-hong-kongs-free-internet) notes

> Mok, the former politician, said authorities might find it difficult to import wholesale Chinese mainland-style internet censorship into Hong Kong “given the telecom regulatory framework is entirely different and a multitude of global and local firms are licensed to provide external connectivity services”.

Comment: Thanks! While this is somewhat reassuring, there's no direct mention of Macau there, and the February 2022 article *As ‘Great Firewall’ looms, fears for Hong Kong’s free internet* focuses on the building pressure for change. I wonder if there is a more direct way to find out if these services are all still available now in September?

Comment: @uhoh Connect to a VPN or proxy server and try, although you cannot be sure that the service lines are not exempt. But you can assume these services are accessible if you cannot find an article from a credible news agency about such services being blocked on the first page of Google.

Comment: @xngtng Certainly some will do that, but no thanks; extraordinary measures like getting and learning to use a VPN or a satellite phone doesn't count as "still accessible" and are more than I can manage. I'm just asking about normal, everyday internet connectivity.

Comment: @uhoh You misunderstood. You can try connecting to a HK or Macau VPN and see if you can still access the services, if you want "direct" verifications.

Comment: @xngtng Oh I see what you mean! Well I certainly wouldn't know how to do that but maybe someone else will, so it's certainly a way to get to an answer. Thanks!*

Comment: Hongkonger here. Yes, all Western apps and websites operate here and there is no expectation that it will change any time soon.

Comment: @Sam Personal experience makes for a great answer

Comment: @Sam yes please consider adding another answer post with your information!